# CakePHP3: validate decimal input

Tags: php, validation, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

This is probably a trivial question, but I can't figure it out.

I want my `price` value to have 2 decimal places. CakePHP should validate this, but it doesn't. CakePHP only checks if the input is a number and doesn't allow to pass decimal values.

I want it to check and pass values like `2.22` but also `2`. Now it only allows the latter.

**Part of `validationDefault` method:**

```
$validator
    ->decimal('price')
    ->allowEmpty('price');
```

I checked CakePHP API and found `decimal()` method description:

> `decimal( float $check , integer|null $places null , string|null $regex null )`
>
> Checks that a value is a valid decimal. Both the sign and exponent are
>   optional.

But it does not take `string` as a parameter in this context(and CakePHP assign `decimal()` to my `price` column automatically during baking), so I guess this is why `decimal('price', 2)` don't work.

Any ideas?

**REQUESTED EDIT:**

**Whole `validationDefault` method:**

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{

   //$validator for other columns

  $validator
        ->allowEmpty('price')
        ->add('price', 'money', array('rule' =>
                          array('money', 'left'),
                          'message' => 'Please supply a valid monetary amount.'));

  return $validator;
}
```

My input field is created using HTML helper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should use money to validate price**

```
 $validator->notEmpty('price',array('message' => 'Please provide your amount'))     
              ->add('price', 'money', array('rule' => array('money','left'),
                                            'message' => 'Please supply a valid monetary amount.'));
```

**Your can also try this**

```
  $validator->notEmpty('amount',array('message' => 'Please provide your amount'))
            ->add('amount','numeric',array('rule' => 'numeric' ,'message'=> 'Please provide a valid amount'));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I copy-paste this line of code (and remove previous `decimal('price')`) but it still want only whole numbers.

Comment: try by removing 'left' its optional ,if not work show me your validation code

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing. Like really embarrassing. I didn't change my table settings in database to accept decimal values  (I've got `decimal(10,0)` instead of `decimal(10,2)`). After fixing it and clearing cache of the app, everything works. I'm sorry for that stupid question and I thank you for your help.